# Adding primary key changes column type

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

Our database currently doesn't define primary keys on any tables. All of the `id` columns are simply unique indexes. I'm dropping those indexes and replacing them with proper primary keys.

**My problem:** In Postgres 8.4.7, one table in particular changes the data type from `bigint` to `integer` when I add the primary key to the table.

I've got the following table definition:

```
psql=# \d events
                                         Table "public.events"
        Column         |           Type           |                      Modifiers                      
-----------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id                    | bigint                   | not null default nextval('events_id_seq'::regclass)
 [more columns omitted]

Indexes:
    "events_id_unique_pk" UNIQUE, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "events_clearing_event_ref_fk" FOREIGN KEY (clearing_event_id) REFERENCES events(id)
    "events_event_configs_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (event_config_id) REFERENCES event_configs(id)
    "events_pdu_circuitbreaker_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (pdu_circuitbreaker_id) REFERENCES pdu_circuitbreaker(id)
    "events_pdu_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (pdu_id) REFERENCES pdus(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "events_pdu_outlet_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (pdu_outlet_id) REFERENCES pdu_outlet(id)
    "events_sensor_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (sensor_id) REFERENCES sensors(id)
    "events_user_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (clearing_user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "events" CONSTRAINT "events_clearing_event_ref_fk" FOREIGN KEY (clearing_event_id) REFERENCES events(id)
    TABLE "event_params" CONSTRAINT "events_params_event_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES events(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Triggers:
    event_validate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON events FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE event_validate()
```

This is what happens:

```
psql=# ALTER TABLE events ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
NOTICE:  ALTER TABLE / ADD PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "events_pkey" for table "events"
ALTER TABLE
psql=# \d events
                                         Table "public.events"
        Column         |           Type           |                      Modifiers                      
-----------------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id                    | integer                  | not null default nextval('events_id_seq'::regclass)
 [more columns omitted]

Indexes:
    "events_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "events_id_unique_pk" UNIQUE, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "events_clearing_event_ref_fk" FOREIGN KEY (clearing_event_id) REFERENCES events(id)
    "events_event_configs_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (event_config_id) REFERENCES event_configs(id)
    "events_pdu_circuitbreaker_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (pdu_circuitbreaker_id) REFERENCES pdu_circuitbreaker(id)
    "events_pdu_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (pdu_id) REFERENCES pdus(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "events_pdu_outlet_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (pdu_outlet_id) REFERENCES pdu_outlet(id)
    "events_sensor_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (sensor_id) REFERENCES sensors(id)
    "events_user_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (clearing_user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "events" CONSTRAINT "events_clearing_event_ref_fk" FOREIGN KEY (clearing_event_id) REFERENCES events(id)
    TABLE "event_params" CONSTRAINT "events_params_event_id_fk" FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES events(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
Triggers:
    event_validate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON events FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE event_validate()
```

I considered a few workarounds, but I'd really rather know why it's happening. There are a few other tables that also use `bigint`, so I don't want to just hack a solution in place.

This is scripted with Liquibase, but it happens directly in the Postgres console too.

---

**Update**

Two other points:

- I can create a simple table with a `bigint` id and a unique index on `id`, add the primary key, and the column type stays the same.
- All tables are empty at the time execution.

Could it have something to do with the constraints?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that adding a primary key constraint could change the type of a column, but let's assume for a while it's a bug. Update to the latest minor version and test again.

Comment: @MilenA.Radev That's the literal output from the console, and those three commands were entered sequentially. We're in the process of upgrading from Postgres 8.4 to 9.1 anyway. I can test against that in a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce this the next day, even after reproducing it multiple times with witnesses the first time it occurred. I'm chalking it up to gremlins.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty interesting.  I can't reproduce it with version 9.1.0 (yes, I should upgrade too!).  But then I don't know precisely how the original table and sequence were created.

This page seems to allude to a similar automatic change of types between SERIAL and INTEGER: http://grover.open2space.com/content/migrate-data-postgresql-and-maintain-existing-primary-key

Could it be something like creating the table using SERIAL instead of BIGSERIAL, and then forcing the type to BIGINT?  Something in between the sequence and primary key manipulations might have reset it.